# distribute the IPA file by fabric.io

Tags: ipa, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I had project whos IPA is been shared by using https://fabric.io/
I am trying to create the IPA file by reading the instruction through this :- https://docs.fabric.io/ios/beta/index.html
But i am not able to understand how should i create the IPA file and upload it to the Beta tab.

I using the command given in this  : https://docs.fabric.io/ios/beta/build-tools.html

> ${SOURCE_ROOT}/Crashlytics.framework/submit XXXXXX XXXXXXXX

when i try to execute this command it give me error :-
-bash: /Users/****/sourcecode/MY_projectpath/Crashlytics.framework: is a directory

Please help me and advice me the step to upload the IPA and share it in 
Note : There is already the ipa exist for the same project which is been shared by other developer.

Comment: check diawi.com its easy to distribute app...

Comment: @FahimParkar I am aware of diawi and testflight.Client want us to share it with the fabric.io.